# My script for jumpin once does not jump at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to test out a fish that will jump out of the water. My script seems fine except when I press the key nothing happens. I was following a simple tutorial and it seems to work for everyone. What am I doing wrong and how can I make this more simple for when referencing it in my capture script later without key down. This is because the fish will jump on its own later.

```
public bool onGround;
private Rigidbody rb;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    onGround = true;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void update ()
{

    if (onGround) 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("a"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3 (0f, 5f, 0f);
            onGround = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Right, might be a spelling error (case sensitive), see TJ Wolschons answer below. For testing you can always add a `Debug.Log`-statement at the point you want to test and see if it actually prints to the console. For last part of your question, just make it a normal function like `public void Jump()` and call that based on the logic you want to use for triggering it (e.g. some cooldown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the more likely thing is that your update function is not correctly setup

Change it to

```
void Update()
```

Comment: I did but it still doesn't seem to react when I press a. I have rigid body on my object too and it falls into the scene fine.

Comment: As per Gunnar's suggestion, try stepping through it in the debugger to find out if it's even getting past either of the if statements